# How to properly convert list of one element to a tuple with one element

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
>>> list=['Hello']
>>> tuple(list)
('Hello',)
```

Why is the result of the above statements `('Hello',)` and not `('Hello')`?. I would have expected it to be the later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got it right.  In python if you do:

```
a = ("hello")
```

`a` will be a string since the parenthesis in this context are used for grouping things together.  It is actually the comma which makes a tuple, not the parenthesis (parenthesis are just needed to avoid ambiguity in certain situations like function calls)...

```
a = "Hello","goodbye"  #Look Ma!  No Parenthesis!
print (type(a)) #<type 'tuple'>
a = ("Hello")
print (type(a)) #<type 'str'>
a = ("Hello",)
print (type(a)) #<type 'tuple'>
a = "Hello",
print (type(a)) #<type 'tuple'>
```

And finally (and most direct for your question):

```
>>> a = ['Hello']
>>> b = tuple(a)
>>> print (type(b))  #<type 'tuple'> -- It thinks it is a tuple
>>> print (b[0])  #'Hello' -- It acts like a tuple too -- Must be :)
```

Comment: Thanks! learned something new today. Never appreciated the subtlety of comma vs parenthesis in tuples.